# Not in Not exists

Tags: sql-server, select

I have three tables

```
table1 -> xt1, yt1, zt1;
table2 -> xt2
table3 -> yt3, zt3


SELECT xt1, yt1, zt1  
From table1, table3 
Where  xt1
NOT IN
   (SELECT  DISTINCT table1.xt1 FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON 
    table1.xt1 = Replace(table2.xt2,',','')) 
And table1.yt1 = table3.yt3
AND table1.zt1 = table3.zt3
```

it is working correctly but i take long time.
if i replace NOT IN with Not exists it return empty set.

```
SELECT xt1, yt1, zt1  
From table1, table3 
Where  Not exists 
(SELECT  DISTINCT table1.xt1 FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON 
    table1.xt1 = Replace(table2.xt2,',','')) 
And table1.yt1 = table3.yt3
AND table1.zt1 = table3.zt3
```

the results of the second select should be 6 rows but it returns notiong with not exists.

also if i tried to change the compare part to 
table1.xt1 != Replace(table2.xt2,',','') and remove the NOT IN
 select it get outof memory error.

So is this the best way to write my query and why it return empty set with Not exists 
thank you.

Comment: Where is `table3` in your query?

Comment: the last two ands and it is in the from sorry for that

Comment: Please also post your NOT EXISTS query.  If it doesn't return results, you are simply implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: @user2320492 Well, I know, I see those, but there's no `table3`  in the `FROM`, nor a join, so....

Comment: I corrected the post

Comment: As @TabAlleman said, your `NOT EXISTS` is wrong, it's not being related to the outer `table1`.

Comment: @Lamak  I'm sorry i'm new to SQL can you explain more.

Comment: `FROM table1 AS t1, table3 AS t3 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON 
    table1.xt1 = Replace(table2.xt2,',','') AND table1.xt1 = t1.xt1) ...`. Or more simply:  `FROM table1 AS t1, table3 AS t3 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM table2 WHERE t1.xt1 = Replace(table2.xt2,',','')) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all, I changed your implicit join to an explicit one. Then I fixed the `NOT EXISTS` so it correlates to the outer `table1`:

```
SELECT t1.xt1, t1.yt1, t1.zt1  
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t1.yt1 = t3.yt3
    AND t1.zt1 = t3.zt3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                    FROM table2 AS t2
                    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1_1 
                        ON t1_1.xt1 = REPLACE(t2.xt2,',','')
                    AND t1_1.xt1 = t1.xt1) ;
```

which can be simplified further to:

```
SELECT t1.xt1, t1.yt1, t1.zt1  
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t1.yt1 = t3.yt3
    AND t1.zt1 = t3.zt3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                    FROM table2 AS t2
                    WHERE t1.xt1 = REPLACE(t2.xt2,',','')
                 ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you it idi work fine when i used the DISTINCT Key word but withoutit it gives the same timing as the one i used. but really thanks But i have two Q if you could have the time: First are the two queries you wrote are the same? second how to know NOT EXISTS  is correct i mean i do not get the Select 1 can you give some resource to read from ?

Comment: I notices that second way is much slower than the first one

Comment: Regarding efficiency, it would be good if you edited the question and added the `CREATE TABLE` scripts, the indexes you have and also the actual execution plans. You may be missing some indexes in the tables or have a datatype mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select IN or exist depending upon the size of inner query. when there is a outer query and inner-sub-query, if the result of sub query is small, In is preferred as outer query is selected based upon result of sub-query.
if the result of sub-query is large, exist is preferred as outer query is evaluated first.

Comment: This query (SELECT  DISTINCT table1.xt1 FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON 
    table1.xt1 = Replace(table2.xt2,',','')) 
 returns 6 rows only but the tables are big.